# Grails 3 curl POST empty content - Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

Hi,
I have Grails 3 application to with file upload option. When I post the curl with empty content it throwing the Exception, What is the best way to handle this condition?

**Curl Posting**

```
curl -v -k -L -X POST -F "filename=@" http://localhost:8080/tools/uploadpackages

> POST /tools/uploadpackages HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.57.0
> Accept: */*
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------649170d4bf695f30
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100
} [155 bytes data]
* read function returned funny value
* stopped the pause stream!
```

**Grails exception**

```
2018-02-26 12:52:08.565 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : EOFException occurred when processing request: [POST] /tools/uploadpackages
Unexpected EOF read on the socket. Stacktrace follows:

org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1104)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsDispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(GrailsDispatcherServlet.groovy:75)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.getHttpMethodOverride(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:71)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:60)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    ... 5 common frames omitted

2018-02-26 12:52:08.566 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[grailsDispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [/tools] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket] with root cause

java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.getHttpMethodOverride(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:71)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thanks
SR

Comment: I'm curious what you would want it to do?   Seems like the UI needs to block sending nothing.

Comment: I am testing all the conditions, no UI for the curl. Also I don’t have control for the client.

Comment: I guess I'm just saying "is this wrong?"   Is sending a multi-part with no content allowable under the standard?

Comment: @billjamesdev  client can post empty body. we need to handle this in the server side code and respond client with correct return code. I found the answer what I am looking for I need use `getSize()` for content size. Here is the API https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE_to_3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.StandardMultipartFile.html